# I found this on the beach at Breamlea in Vic Australia and wondered if you could tell me what it is please

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology

It is about 6.5 x 5 centimetres and semi transparent.
It has quite a tough skin and is hollow inside. Like a tight clear tooth shaped balloon. I have put a coin next to it for you to see the size.

[image]

Comment: Dentist merchandise?

Answer (score 5):

It's a swim bladder, probably a [porcupinefish swim bladder](https://australianmuseum.net.au/image/porcupinefish-gas-bladder). They can be found washed ashore still inflated. They've been described as "molar shaped". (Picture from Australian Museum.)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to tell exactly, but if I had to bet I'd say it's a small part of an algae called **[Neptune's necklace:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hormosira)**

[image]

Some species are native to New Zealand and Australia. Where two "branches" split, the shape you found can be produced.

Looks like they're also found in your area: http://bie.ala.org.au/species/NZOR-4-7414